# Delta-V for station keeping

Tags: station-keeping

How can I calculate the necessary thrust to keep a satellite of 1 kg mass in orbit, for a Delta-V of 2 m/s, knowing that the correction force must be done once a month for 900 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you need to get 2 m/s delta-v by thrusting for a period of 900 seconds, it's [very straightforward to ask Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1kg%20*%202%20m%2Fs%20%2F%20900s%20):

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Apparently [1 newton is equal to 101.97162129779 pond](https://www.convertunits.com/info/pond) I'd never seen that unit before.